# Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\ClientController does not exist Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I am trying to run an api on postman, I am getting this error:

"ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\ClientController does not exist in file /home/nosi/myProjects/paylesotho/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 752"

below is what I did:
my controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function registerClient(request $request){
        $merchant_code=$request->input('merchant_code');
        $email_address=$request->input('email_address');
        $company_name=$request->input('company_name');
        $service_provider=$request->input('service_provider');
        $password=$request->input('password');
        $confirm_password=$request->input('confirm_password');
        $client = DB::insert('insert into clients_info(id, merchant_code, email_address, company_name, service_provider, passoword, confirm_password) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [null, $merchant_code, $email_address, $company_name, $service_provider, $password, $confirm_password]);
        if($client){
            return redirect('clients_info')->with('status', 'Client Registered Successfully');
        }

    }

}
```

below is my route code :

```
Route::post('/register','Api\ClientController@registerClient')->name('registerClient');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mentioned your controller directory, I am Assuming your controller directory is app/Http/Controller/Api,  your namespace is incorrect.

namespace must be.  `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;`
and don't forget to import controller.

If your controller is not inside `Api` directory, you need to remove `/Api` from Your route.